# LISTAGG fails with SQLCODE=-440

Tags: sql, db2, aggregate

I am getting this error when I try to use `LISTAGG`

No authorized routine named "LISTAGG" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=3.58.81

I am using **DB2 9.7.0.8.**

Here is the query:

`SELECT  LISTAGG(columna,',') FROM table GROUP BY columb`

columna is a `varchar`
columnb is `int` and the `pk`

Comment: Apparently, you are supplying incorrect arguments to the function. Since you chose not to show the actual SQL statement, you'll have to figure out the details by yourself.

Comment: @mustaccio
SELECT  LISTAGG(columna,',') FROM table 
          GROUP BY columb
columna is a varchar
columnb is int and the pk

Comment: Why don't you put this in your question, properly formatted?

Comment: The bogus statement as shown looks correct, so there are few possibilities: 1) Your DB2 server version is not 9.7 fix pack 8, or the fix pack was incorrectly installed. 2) `columna` data type is not `varchar` and cannot be cast to `varchar` 3) Your _actual_ query contains an error.

Comment: By the way, if as you say `columnb` is the primary key, what is the point of grouping by it? The result would be equivalent to that of `select columna from table`.

Comment: @mustaccio columnb is not unique. It is one of the PK. This table has compounded pk. I found another solution using xmlagg.
Here is the reference: https://gist.github.com/zarkosusnjar/1675843

Answer (score 0):

columnb is not unique, It is one of the PK. This table has compounded pk.

Solution is [here](https://gist.github.com/zarkosusnjar/1675843)

*Since here is no answer posted and correct answer is posted as comment so posting this answer from comment of @Ravi*